# How to obatain the following one to one function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

$$ f(x,k) = y$$
$$x<=k$$
$$x,k \in R$$
$$y \in [0,1]$$

The domain of the function would be $x$ to $k$ and the range would be $0$ to $1$. such that for $x=x$ the $y=0.0$ and for $x=k$ , $y=1.0$, the value of $y$ increases with $x$. How to obtain such a function

Comment: You are using the symbol $x$ to refer to two different things, I think. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting your question as a monotonic function from $[j,k]$ to $[0,1]$ with $f(j)=0$ and $f(k)=1$ where $j \lt k$, then $$f(x)= \dfrac{x-j}{k-j}$$ does this simply